# Why is the 'public' access modifier used with event Action delegates that always behave 'private'

Tags: c#, delegates, action

```
public class Pub
{
    public event Action OnChange = delegate {};

    public void Raise()
    {
        OnChange();
    }
}
```

This is listing 1-83 from programming in C#
The author writes:
'Another change is that no outside users can raise your event. It can be raised only by code that's part of the class that defined the event.'

If that is the case shouldn't you use the private modifier for clarity ?

Comment: Raising event is only winthin class defining the event, if you make action delegate private then how other object will subscribe to it?

Comment: if(OnChange != null) should be added to your code, because `OnChange()` will fail is there're no event handlers for this event...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer That's what the `= delegate {}` is for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that the event is marked `public` means that it can be *subscribed* to publically - anyone can add an `Action` delegate and it will be called when the event fires. If you marked the event `private` you would only be able to subscribe to it from within the class. (`protected`: only from within the class or its inheritors, `internal`: only from within the assembly and so on.)

An event can always only be *fired* from within the class, as if the "fire this event" method were marked `private`. This is unaffected by the event's actual access modifier.